# Source on the 4 types of ways to protect the 5 precepts

Tags: sutras, five-precepts

Recently I got to know that there are 4 types of ways to protect the 5 precepts.

Such as

1. You don't do it
2. You don't make others do it
3. You don't support others to do it
4. You don't praise and talk about it.

Where can I find the sutta source? Please provide the sutta link kindly

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are 3 ways (of kamma), not four ("ultimatly" one incharge of the others, mind).

"Don't support others..." can be made in three ways as well, and the teachings are full of repeating about the kamma by own physical deeds (kaya-kamma), by verbal deeds (vicāra-, this included signs and gestures as well) and by mind/thoughts (citta-, approval, taking in account for ones own benefit, agreement, joy..., ignorance).

[Kammapathapeyyālaṃ](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.164-183.sang_en.html) might possible give ways to approve.

To protect ones Sila, only one is required: either right view (than it would work out by itself), or strong faith into it, if not gained yet. Silas without the protection of right view are not really Silas but just better or more worse rituals, not penetrating till the mind.

If sensedoor are not guided one breaks the Silas (as factors of the path) actually all the time, steals/kills forms, sounds, smells, tastes, touches, thoughts. Having no silas, there will be no samma samadhi > no pañña > no right release: mostly just nurishing defilements. Without leaving home and become homeless (leaving the senses behind), it's not possible to develope the path, Silas, Samādhi, Pañña and gain release.

*[Note: this is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for any worldly exchange and trade]*

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what you were asking for, this is related. The "four" in this case is four types of individuals, not four ways to protect. But the spirit of the sutta follows the general spirit of your inquiry. Your phrase "You don't praise and talk about it." would fall under the general category of lying and [nonsense speech](https://suttacentral.net/an3.163-182/en/sujato)

Per [AN4.99 Trainings](https://suttacentral.net/an4.99/en/thanissaro) from the Book of Fours discusses four types of individuals. This is the fourth:

> “And how is one an individual who practices for his own benefit and for that of others? There is the case where a certain individual himself abstains from the taking of life and encourages others in undertaking abstinence from the taking of life. He himself abstains from stealing and encourages others in undertaking abstinence from stealing. He himself abstains from sexual misconduct and encourages others in undertaking abstinence from sexual misconduct. He himself abstains from lying and encourages others in undertaking abstinence from lying. He himself abstains from intoxicants that cause heedlessness and encourages others in undertaking abstinence from intoxicants that cause heedlessness. Such is the individual who practices for his own benefit and for that of others

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Sutta basket,The Vinaya basket of the [Tipitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka) gives a lot more detailed info. on all the conditions of what constitutes the breaking of the precepts. Ex: on the taking of life: https://suttacentral.net/pli-tv-bu-vb-pj3/en/brahmali